# Greeting User using FORM input and Query String

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to read the user's name from a “Form” text input and display it somewhere on the page in a greeting message i.e. Hello (user). I need to use the “Form” input and extract the user’s name from the URL using the query string. I also need to read the query string when the page is loaded, not when the button is pressed i.e. need to write a function for the `onload` event
This all must be done in one HTML file not two separate HTML files.
Any help will be appreciated!

```
             <form>         
                <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter your name!">         
                <button type="submit">Apply!</button>       
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// use the ids to access the elements in the DOM
const userName = document.getElementById("user-name");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

// if there query string is not empty
if (location.search !== '') {

  // get the parameters
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  
  // pick out the user name
  const un = params.get("user_name");
  
  // update the input and the display
  output.textContent = userName.value = un;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter your name!">
  <button type="submit">Apply!</button>
</form>
<p>Hello <output id="output"></output></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need to use Query String to achieve the outcome (read the user's name in the URL after ? and before #)

Comment: `location.search` is the query string. I tested the code in a standalone page, it works. I don't think it is reliable in the snippet interface.

Comment: @user20481542 of course it works...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search
Mark the question as solved so.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a 'keyup' event listener. See code snippet below for an example.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="h1">Hello World</h1>

    <form>         
        <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter your name!" id="input">         
        <button type="submit">Apply!</button>       
    </form> 
    <script>
        // update the body h1 element with real-time user input
        function updateH1() {
            var h1 = document.getElementById("h1");
            var input = document.getElementById("input");
            h1.innerHTML = input.value;
        }
        // call updateH1() when the user types in the input element
        function init() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input");
            input.addEventListener("keyup", updateH1);
        }
        // call init() when the page loads
        window.addEventListener("load", init);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need to use Query String to achieve the outcome (read the user's name in the URL after ? and before #)